# LVM_CREATEDRAGIMAGE CListCtrl::CreateDragImage fails to create image for the text too

Tags: listview, winapi, mfc, drag-and-drop

I have an application and I have several classes that derives from CListCtrl.

Now I have the case were I have a report list control inside a dialog. I call CreateDragImage (LVM_CREATEDRAGIMAGE) and the drag image only contains the icon. The text is missing.

The same application in another case with another class (derived from CListCtrl) the drag image is created with text.

I found some [links](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/wtl/conversations/topics/5110) (very old), that say it is a font problem. But in both cases the font is set by the underlying dialog. Is is the standard "MS Shell Dlg".

What is the reason here? How can I fix it to get a complete correct drag image?

**EDIT:**

I found out that a colleague wrote a code, that subclassed the list view that has a working drag image. Due to the subclass the change wasn't obvious and the comments say that he got the same problems :(. The code is over 12 years old. The LVM_CREATEDRAGIMAGE is handled there on a "private" way. But I am still wondering, why the standard code didn't work. I moved the subclass into the existing list views, so I have a *hack*, but the question is still open.

Comment: Is there any owner-drawing/custom-drawing going on in the list view, that fails to construct the desired drag icon?

Comment: The implementation creates a drag icon, but it consists only of the icon itself. No function in the chain fails. Drag&Drop works. The code in both classes is nearly identical.

Comment: In that case the source code constructing the drag-and-drop icon could be useful, and should be part of the question.

Comment: Step 1, disable all your custom draw (comment out your `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` handler entirely) and see if it still happens. If it does you know where to look.

Comment: There are no custom draw handlers in the code. I placed an Edit in the question.